# Common vocabulary between Common Lisp and Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp

There are many differences between Common Lisp and Scheme such as whether functions and variables share a namespace, whether macros are hygienic, and how strongly functional style is preferred; this shows up in some vocabulary differences such as `setq`  vs `set!`.

But quite a bit of vocabulary is still shared, such as `quote` and `cons`.

I'm looking for a full list of vocabulary shared between the languages. Does such a thing exist?

Alternatively, I could make one myself given the vocabulary of each language, i.e. a list of all the known symbols including language primitives, standard library macros and functions. Do those exist for Common Lisp (as in the standard) and Scheme (as in any RxRS, or failing that, any dialect)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this web page:

http://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp

Comment: While `#lang racket` is a close descendant of Scheme it is not a Scheme. Eg `null`/ `true`/ `false` is not mentioned in any report. Ancient reports had `#true`/`#false` though.  The `for` and `for/*` forms are specifically `#lang racket` forms. I found the page cool though.

Comment: True. Btw @rwallace There are also a few inaccuracies in the list. One I noticed is the representation of identifiers: In Racket the symbol `'foo` is not used to represent the identifier `foo`. Instead the syntax object `#'foo` is used.

Answer (score 4):

Get all symbols of Common Lisp:

```
(sort (loop for sym being each external-symbol of "CL" collect sym)
      #'string-lessp)
```

Comment: An interesting question (to me, anyway) is: is there an equivalent of this in portable Scheme?  I think there is not, but I'd be interested if there were.